# Finite difference scheme for Webster equation

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, wave-propagation

Webster equation is a popular generalization of 1D wave equation used for ducts of variable cross-section $S \equiv S(x)$. Assuming harmonicity in time, the spatial equation for propagation of variable $\Phi(x)$ is:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial (\ln S(x))}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial x} + k^2\Phi^2 = 0
$$

What FD scheme would be appropriate assuming that we have boundary conditions at $\Phi(0)$ and $\Phi(L)$, i.e. no $\partial_x\Phi(0)$ etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point regarding boundary conditions. Do you mean you have $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(L)$ prescribed, i.e. dirichlet boundary conditions?

Comment: That's it. Sorry for confusing assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something I've worked on, so I do not know if there is a recommended approach to this, only how I would approach this problem.

I'm assuming you can evaluate $C(x) = (\ln(S(x)))_x$ wherever you want.

Since $\phi$ is prescribed at $0$ and $L$, I would discretise on $x_i = L\frac{i}{N+1}$ for $i$ from $1$ to $N$. Then the finite difference operators could be combined into a matrix $A$ and boundary condition correction term vector $\mathbf{b}$ with
$$\begin{gathered}
A = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}\delta^2_x + \frac1{2\Delta x}\mathrm{diag}(C(x_i))\delta_{2x}\,,\\
\mathbf{b}_i = 
\begin{cases}
  \left(\frac1{\Delta x^2} - \frac1{2\Delta x}c(x_1)\right)\phi(0)\quad&\text{if}\quad i=1\,,\\
  \left(\frac1{\Delta x^2} + \frac1{2\Delta x}c(x_N)\right)\phi(L) &\text{if}\quad i=N\,,\\
0&\text{otherwise}\,,
\end{cases}
\end{gathered}
$$
 so that
$$\left[\phi_{xx} + C(x)\phi_x\right]_{x_i} \approx (A\underline{\phi} + \mathbf{b})_i\,.$$

To find the solution, I would use Newton's method, looking for the root of
$$F(\underline{\phi}) = A\underline{\phi} + \mathbf{b} + k^2 \mathrm{diag}(\phi_i^2)$$
which has tridiagonal Jacobian
$$\mathrm{J}(\underline{\phi}) = A + 2k^2 \mathrm{diag}(\phi_i)\,.$$

(For completion) If there were a Neumann boundary condition, for example
$$\phi_x(0) = \alpha\,,$$
I would include $\phi(0)$ in the solution vector $\underline{\phi}$, then I would construct $\mathrm{b}$ by considering a *ghost point* at $x = -\Delta x$ satisfying
$$\frac{\phi(\Delta x) - \phi(-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x} = \alpha\,.$$
I believe mixed boundary conditions wouldn't be much more complicated than non-zero Neumann.